# Find pattern from regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex pattern

```
^(?:(?:31(\\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\\\/|-|\\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(\\\/|-|\\.)0?2\\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(\\\/|-|\\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$
```

Can anyone tell me how to find possible matches from this regex pattern?

Comment: Paste your regex in https://regex101.com/

Comment: I don't know any possible match. In this case, can i know any?

Comment: Well, you could try to understand what this regex actually does... When you have accomplished that, your question would no longer be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.debuggex.com) is what your regular expression flow looks like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To get you started (and of course for the sake of brevity), let's always take the top most routes :)

First of all, we have three ways to go, we'll choose the top most one!, there, `^` indicates the start of the string, after that we may encounter `31` or `29` or `30`, but following the rule of choosing the top most one we've just made;), we go for `31`, and after that there maybe the character sequence of `\/` (other possibilities are `-` and `\.`).

Then there could be `0` in our path or not, (we'll choose the "not" case!), and then one of `1, 3, 5, 7, 8`, then the character sequence of `\1`, then we have a three-way ahead, we go with the top most one to the occurrence of `\`, and then `dd` (a two times `d`), and we're finally there, where should be the end of string. What a journey!!

So, one possible match could be `31\/1\1\dd`. Now it's your turn, take the other routes :)